# How to insert 50k products in woocomerce from json response using cron job?

Tags: woocommerce

I want to insert 50k products in woocommerce using cron job. Data will come from json API. SO please guide me how can I do this job ?

```
$fileContents = file_get_contents(ABSPATH.'json_array.txt');
if ($fileContents === false) 
{
    echo 'ERROR!';
} 
else 
{                   
    $data = json_decode($fileContents, true);
    // count($data['DataList']; output 50000
    for($i=0;$i<count($data['DataList']);$i++)
    {
        $Shape = $data->DataList[$i]->Shape;
        $Size = $data->DataList[$i]->Size;
        $Color = $data->DataList[$i]->Color;
        $Clarity = $data->DataList[$i]->Clarity;

        $objProduct = new WC_Product();
        $objProduct->set_name($ReportNo); //Set product name.
        $objProduct->set_status('publish');
        $objProduct->set_featured(TRUE);
        $objProduct->set_catalog_visibility('visible');
        $new_product_id = $objProduct->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the problem in writing code for that? Have you tried anything so far and run into problems?

Comment: @NicoHaase : I edit the above question with code.

Comment: And what's the problem with the given code? Does anything not work yet?

Comment: @NicoHaase: If json response 1000 records then it will work smoothly, but when above 5000 records then not work properly.  some insert only 1200 or 2000 records.

Comment: Then you should either chunk the imports (run only 1k at a time), use some proper importing (eg. write raw queries instead of using your ORM), or check **why** this happens - is there any error message given? Does the `max_execution_time` limit stop the execution?